# How do I pass a argument in this function

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am working On a shopping cart function, but I want to send product id's to This javascript part.

```
    $(".qtybutton").on("click", function(){
        var $button = $(this);
        var oldValue = $button.parent().find("input").val();
        var id = $button.parent().find("key").val();
        if ($button.text() === "+") {

            var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
            $.post("cart_session.php", {action:'call_this', newVal: newVal },
            function(data) {
                $('#results').html(data);
            });
        }
```

This is the html part.

```
<div class="dec qtybutton">-</div>
<form method="POST">
<input class="cart-plus-minus-box" type="integer" value="2" disabled>
</form>
<div class="inc qtybutton">+</div>
```

I want to will pass argument with php ex:- `function(<?= $key?>)`, I want to know how do I do this?

Comment: where is the 5? In your example, where is the product id?

Comment: The button isn't inside the form, so $button.parent() will not return the form, and you could end up with the wrong input element.

Comment: I will use php for that it ex :-  function(<?= $key?>)

Comment: @Samurai I suggest storing the `product id` in a hidden input type. Then you can easily get that data.

Comment: I did it, I put html in another div, set that divs id as product id, And then Called the parent id to javascript function.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest putting the product id in the form field as a data attribute. That way you can always associate the product id with the quantity.

```js
$(".qtybutton").on("click", function() {
  let $button = $(this), $inc = $button.closest('.q-cont').find("input")
  let newVal = Math.max(0,+$inc.val() + +$button.data('inc'))
  $inc.val(newVal);
  let id = $inc.data('productid');
  console.log('newVal:', $inc.val(), 'id:', id)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='q-cont'>
  <div class="dec qtybutton" data-inc="-1">-</div>
  <form method="POST">
    <input class="cart-plus-minus-box" data-productid="5" type="integer" value="2" disabled>
  </form>
  <div class="inc qtybutton" data-inc="1">+</div>
</div>
```